# Find exact insert statement on trigger (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, triggers

I need to find the exact insert statement in trigger.
I need a trigger like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER insertusers BEFORE INSERT ON users
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    INSERT INTO userlog(userid,statement)
    VALUES(NEW.userid,**EXACT_INSERT_STATEMENT**);
END;
```

Is there any trick for doing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is not unfortunately.